# File missing when using MSBuild to compile Android app

Tags: android, delphi, deployment

I have an app that compiles fine in the IDE (10.4.2). I am trying to make Continua build it with MSBuild. And I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(585,5): warning : Local file "" not found. Skipping deployment.
```

What is that "local file" that obviously is missing?
Here is the complete parameterlist to MSBuild:

```
/nologo /verbosity:diagnostic /target:"Build";"Deploy" /P:platform=Android64 /P:config=Release /P:BT_BuildType=AppStore /P:DCC_ExeOutput=C:\CI_AWS\Ws\5259\Output /P:VerInfo_Keys="Fileversion=1.0.0.145" /P:outputpath="C:\CI_AWS\Ws\5259\Output" /P:configuration="Release" /noconsolelogger /nodeReuse:False /logger:ParallelLogger,"C:\Program Files\VSoft Technologies\ContinuaCI Agent\Continua.Modules.Builds.MSBuild.v40.dll" C:\CI_AWS\Ws\5259\Source\MM\KlotetAdmCS\Client\KlotetAdmClient.dproj
```